# Faulty image-hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have four equally sized images, all set to 20% width of the page

```
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="#">
</div>
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="#">
</div>
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="#">
</div>
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

in my website that are horizontally aligned. On hover, I want the image to zoom inside the original border (like this https://codepen.io/math2001/pen/zZXBbj?editors=1100), which I did by a CSS3 transition and overflow: hidden.

```
.portrait {
float: left;
width: 20%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.portrait img {
width: 100%;
transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.portrait img:hover {
transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

The width of the image does not overflow past the original 20% constraint of the portrait, but the height does. I know the problem is that there is no fixed constraint for the height of the wrapper divs, but I don't know how to create one, since everything is percentage scaled. How can I fix this?

Comment: How does my answer not solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

Put the `transform` on the container rather than the image:

```css
.portrait {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:transform 0.2s linear;
}
.portrait img {
  width:100%;
}
.portrait:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
</div>
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/000/ccc">
</div>
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/aaa/eee">
</div>
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250/ccc/fff">
</div>
```

Comment: I want the image to zoom, but still retain its dimensions. Can that be done? I added a codepen to clarify what I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use bigger definition for scale. For example:

```
.portrait:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `img` to `display:block;`

```css
.portrait {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.portrait img {
  display: block;                       /*  added property  */
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}
.portrait:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="portrait">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250/f99">
</div>
```